# Is it possible to save state of Web application

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I build a Web application using GWT (and/or SmartGWT) that uses a number of forms to collect data. Is it possible to save the progress so that the user can leave the application and when comes back continues with the data (s)he has already entered?

If yes, do I have to use a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course.

One of the way is use the GWT 's RPC framework to make calls to Java servlets . 
You do not need a  database to store the form data as  you can store the form data inside the [HttpSession](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) object provided by the Java servlets  . You can imagine `HttpSession`  has a built-in data store that allows you to store any number of key/value pairs and each client has their own `HttpSession`.

You can refer to the followings links/ tutorials to get the basic ideas .

---

**References**

- [Using Servlet Sessions in GWT – Tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=230)
- [Google Web Toolkit (GWT) & Servlets - Web application tutorial](http://lkamal.blogspot.com/2008/09/java-gwt-servlets-web-app-tutorial.html)
- [Google official document - Communicate with a Server](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideRemoteProcedureCalls.)

Comment: so if the user comes back later to the application, it is possible to reload the form (and other controls or not?) with previous entered data? (because i do not find a saveData()-like method in FormPanel).

Comment: You have to add the data you want to store by using `HttpSession .setAttribute()` . Then when the user come backs and if the session does not timeout yet , you can use `HttpSession.getAttribute()` to get back these values to reconstruct the form

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to store the data in the browser. This way you won't need a server-side database.

You can either use browser cookies (note that cookies expire...):
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/Cookies.html

Or the all new GWT HTML5 storage API:
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/storage/client/Storage.html